# Twitter Bootstrap Columns and Angular Order By

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, angularjs-orderby

I keep running into this problem and haven't found a good solution that doesn't cause layout issues. What's the best way to display an array of items, sorted alphabetically, in columns? I'm using ng-repeat to iterate over an array and display a checkbox for each item. I want the data to be displayed in n columns, alphabetically i.e., not alphabetically in rows.

***alphabetically in colums***

```
|item a| |item d| |item g|
|item b| |item e| ...
|item c| |item f| ...
```

***current implementation - alphabetically in rows***

```
  <div class="checkbox col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3" ng-repeat="user in user.results | orderBy:'lastName' track by user.id">
    <input id="{{ user.id }}" type="checkbox">
    {{ user.lastName }}, {{ user.firstName }}
    <label for="{{ user.id }}" class="pull-left checkbox-label"></label>
  </div>
```

***Edit***

I originally went with the dynamic bootstrap method but this actually screwed up the checkbox behavior i.e., clicking a checkbox resulted in the incorrect checkbox being checked. I'm trying fix this using flexbox but I haven't used it before and don't understand how to dynamically change the column count without having to set a fixed height on the flex container. I would like to have one column on small/extra small screens and three columns for medium/large screens.

```
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-item {
  background: green;
    width: 33%;
}

/* Small screens */
@media all and (max-width: @container-tablet) {
  .flex-item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

  <div class="flex-box">
    <div class="flex-item" ng-repeat="country in region.countries | orderBy:'name' track by $index">
      <input id="{{ country.isoCode }}" checklist-model="vm.selectedCountries.value[region.name]" checklist-value="country" type="checkbox" ng-change="vm.setRegionCountry(region, country, checked)">
      <label for="{{ country.isoCode }}" class="pull-left checkbox-label"></label>
      <span>{{ country.name | limitTo:17 }}{{country.name.length > 17 ? '...' : ''}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

***Solution***

```
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

/* Small screens */
@media all and (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    .flex-box {
        max-height: 375px;
    }
}
/* Medium screens */
@media all and (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    .flex-box {
        max-height: 550px;
    }
}
/* Large screens */
@media all and (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    .flex-box {
        max-height: 375px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using flexbox?

Comment: Do you want n-columns or n-rows? `|item a| |item d| |item g|` looks not alphabetically in the columns. They seem alphabetically in the rows. Please confirm both.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve alphabetically in columns i.e., read from top to bottom and then to the next column so, item a, item b, item c, -> next column item d, item e, item f...

Comment: @bob, flexbox looks like a possibility, going to look into this more.

Comment: I have included some example code in my answer. Check out the css-tricks link for great info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak little bit as below if you want to use with `bootstrap`. Otherwise you can use either `flex-box` or `column-count`.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TestController', function($scope){
  $scope.fixedColumn = 3;
  
  $scope.getColumns = function(){
    return new Array($scope.fixedColumn);
  };
  
  $scope.getColumnWidth = function(){
    return Math.floor(12 / $scope.fixedColumn);
  };
  
  $scope.getRowCount = function(){
    return Math.ceil($scope.user.results.length / $scope.fixedColumn);
  };
  
  $scope.user = {
    results: [
      {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'FirstName1',
        lastName: 'LastName1'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        firstName: 'FirstName2',
        lastName: 'LastName2'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        firstName: 'FirstName3',
        lastName: 'LastName3'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        firstName: 'FirstName4',
        lastName: 'LastName4'
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        firstName: 'FirstName5',
        lastName: 'LastName5'
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        firstName: 'FirstName6',
        lastName: 'LastName6'
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        firstName: 'FirstName7',
        lastName: 'LastName7'
      },
      {
        id: 8,
        firstName: 'FirstName8',
        lastName: 'LastName8'
      }
    ]
  };
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-controller="TestController">
<div class="row" ng-repeat="u in user.results | orderBy:'lastName' track by u.id" ng-init="pIndex=$index" ng-if="$index < getRowCount()">
  <div ng-repeat="col in getColumns() track by $index" ng-init="usr = user.results[pIndex + ($index * getRowCount())]" ng-class="'col-xs-'+ getColumnWidth() + ' col-sm-'+ getColumnWidth() + ' col-md-'+ getColumnWidth()" ng-if="user.results.length > (pIndex + ($index * getRowCount()))">
    <input id="{{ usr.id }}" type="checkbox">
    {{ usr.lastName }}, {{ usr.firstName }}
    <label for="{{ usr.id }}" class="pull-left checkbox-label"></label>
  </div> 
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the detailed answer. I've been looking for a solution to this for a while. I'm surprised there is not a directive to handle this. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.flex-box {
        height: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .flex-item {
            background: green;
            text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="flex-box">
                <div class="flex-item" ng-repeat="user in user.results | orderBy:'lastName'">{{user.id}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using CSS flexbox you can dynamically add as many column as required for your data set https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without bootstrap using columns. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ojzdxpt1/1/

```
#wrapper {
    column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-count:3;
}
.col {
  background:#ccc;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

`#wrapper` contains each repeater. See more about css columns

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts
- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/